# Percent Overlap between Observations

Tags: r, matrix

Preference cards identify the resources and preferences for specific surgical procedures, including surgical materials and equipment. Each surgeon has their own preference card for surgeries. I am interested in examining the overlap in items from one surgeon to the next (via heatmap).

Example:

```
Physician   Item 1  Item 2  Item 3
1            Yes    Yes      No
2            Yes    Yes      No
3            No     No       Yes
4            No     No       Yes
```

Physician 1 & 2 have 100% Overlap in items used (e.g. all items used match)
Physician 1 & 3 have 0% Overlap in items used (e.g. none of the items used match)
Physician 1 & 4 have 0% Overlap in items used
Physician 2 & 3 have 0% Overlap in items used
Physician 2 & 4 have 0% Overlap in items used
Physician 3 & 4 have 33.3% Overlap in items used (e.g. 1 of 3 items match)

In table form this would look like

```
Physician   1       2      3      4
1          100%         
2          100%   100%      
3            0%     0%    100%  
4            0%     0%     33%   100%
```

Comment: This is super unclear. Consider re-approaching your description with examples of your data/code. As it stands this is too difficult for someone not familiar with your work to decipher. Also, please take time to understand how to present code etc. here.

Comment: the data doesn't seem to jibe. can you please explain the 33% between physician 3 and 4?

Comment: @jdukes If you consider the overlap among `Yes` ie 33% (among 3rd and 4th physician), then by that logic, the 1 and 2 overlap should be 66%

Comment: My apologies that 33% is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `33%` overlap is a typo, you could do:

```
r1 <- combn(df$Physician, 2, FUN=function(x) {
                     x1 <- match(x[1], df$Physician)
                     x2 <- match(x[2], df$Physician)
         c(paste0(100*sum(df[x1,-1]==df[x2,-1])/ncol(df[,-1]), "%"), 
                                         paste(x1, x2, sep=" "))})


indx <- as.matrix(read.table(text=r1[2,]))
res <- matrix('', ncol=nrow(df), nrow=nrow(df),
             dimnames=list(df$Physician, df$Physician))

res[dim(res)[1]+1 - indx] <- r1[1,]
diag(res) <- '100%'
as.data.frame(res)
#    1    2    3    4
#1 100%               
#2 100% 100%          
#3   0%   0% 100%     
#4   0%   0% 100% 100%
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(Physician = 1:4, Item.1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"No"), Item.2 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"), Item.3 = c("No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes")), .Names = c("Physician", "Item.1", "Item.2", 
"Item.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```